# Understanding the word מִצְוַת in וְכָל מִצְוַת שְׁמוֹנַת יְמֵי חֲנֻכָּה in HaNeros Hallalu

Tags: chanuka, nuschaot

In some versions of *HaNeros Hallalu*, the following wording is included:

> וְכָל מִצְוַת שְׁמוֹנַת יְמֵי חֲנֻכָּה הַנֵּרוֹת הַלָּלוּ קֹדֶשׁ

(Found, e.g., in [Siddur Tefillah Yesharah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7190&st=%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%95&pgnum=484), thanks to @ezra for the link.)

In the other versions, the word מִצְוַת is left out. With the word מִצְוַת included, the syntax seems odd. How would you understand it?

Comment: "And throughout the entire mitzvah of the eight days of Chanukah these lights are holy." That's how I translate it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I will add that in early editions of Nusach Sfard siddurim, there isn't always great grammar, because the creators of these siddurim didn't really pay attention to this when they tried blending Nusach Ashkenaz and Edot Hamizrach and Kabbalah together. Hence the Alter Rebbe's plan to correct grammar in his siddur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Minhagei Yisrael article I quoted in my answer to [Versions of HaNeros Hallalu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97229/versions-of-haneros-hallalu/97294#97294), Rabbi Sperber notes that this is found in the version of the Rosh.

He suggests that it may have been added to support the opinion in the Gemara Shabbos that listening to the Rabbis' Chanukah Mitzvos (and saying Asher Kideshanu Bemitzvosav **Vetzivanu**) is supported by the verse of "Lo Sasur", which seems like a commandment (mitzvah), as opposed to the other opinion there, that it is derived from "She'al Avicha", which sounds more like it is optional. He further notes that the Yerushalmi's version of the Bracha is Vetzivanu Al Mitzvas Hadlakas Ner Chanukah.

**Basically, it would mean and all the 8 commanded days of Chanukah, but it is awkward grammar.**

In his words:
[image]
[image]