# Structure and Rhyme of early songs

Tags: jewish-books, song-poetry, chazal

I was hoping someone could help me. I am trying to understand the structure and rhythm of Teffilos and Piyutim written by chazal or early Rishonim. understanding the zemiros of shabbos and other songs.
FOR EXAMPLE:
הנרות הללו, clearly has a set structure,

הנרות הללו אנו מדליקין a
על התשועות ועל הנסים ועל הנפלאותc
שעשית לאבותינו על ידי כהניך הקדושים
וכל (מצות) שמנת ימי חנוכה
הנרות הללו קודש ואין לנו רשות להשתמש בהן אלא לראותן בלבד a
כדי להודות לשמך b
cעל נפלאותיך ועל נסיך ועל ישועתך
We can see that lines A are connected and lines C are connected (yet in reverse) the middle 2 lines I am trying to work on.
I need any seforim or books written in English or Hebrew that discuss this (ideally something available on university digital libraries)
Thank you!

Comment: discussing structure and rhythm is difficult when you are using a single version of the text -- others insert or delete (or change) words which leads to different rhythms and structures https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%95

Comment: Hanerot halalu is not a great example since there are lots of versions and it's not entirely clear who wrote it / adapted it or if it was intended as poetry https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97294/759 On the face of it it's a straight stipulation as part of the liturgy: we light a candle and declare these are chanuka candles. Without a declaration they are just candles.

Comment: Thank you from all the versions I saw the basic structure is the same, there are some word differences. I could have picked many different examples this was just one which I am working on.
If anyone knows books on the subject or a sefer please let me know!!
Thanks